# sentence identification/detection: decide whether some text is a sentence or not

Tags: java, nlp

Most sentence splitters are able to split a stream of text at the correct position.

I am looking for a model that will **decide whether some text is a sentence or not**.

Comment: I think part of you question was left off...please take a look and see if it's complete.

Comment: @joshp The fact that you detected that means you must have some sort of text-is-sentence detection! :-)

Comment: Even though I am a lowly carbon based life form, I do have sentence detection.

Answer (score 4):

Easy solution: Use a parser (for example, the Stanford Parser, which is free and Java, but there are many options) to parse the sentence.  If the parser returns a parse tree (ie, if it finds some appropriate structure), then call it a sentence.  If it doesn't, then say it's not.  This approach requires no extra effort on your part.

The caveat is that by its very nature, a statistical parser may return a "best guess" parse for a sentence that is actual ungrammatical.  Thus, it is possible for an ungrammatical sentence to show up as "ok" under this scheme.

If, on the other hand, you want to be very specific about what *is* or *is not* proper grammar according to your system, you could write your own context-free grammar (CFG) and then use a CFG-based parser to parse the sentence (you could find one or implement the CKY algorithm or something).  This will tell you *precisely* whether the sentence meets the grammatical specification you provided or not.

Of course this question is touching on the dangerous subject of "[what does it mean to be a sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticality)" which many linguists will fight you over.  It also side-steps the issues of grammatical sentences that don't seem to mean anything such as "[Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously)" or a zillion other semantic issues.

Comment: Or something like, "The dog walked around the barn peed." It'd be easy for a grammar to think the sentence ends after "barn," in which case "dog" is the subject and the verb is "walked." But the sentence really means "(The dog [who was] walked around the barn) peed," in which "dog" is the subject, the verb is "peed," and "walked around the barn" is a subordinate clause. Human language parsing is going to need a _lot_ of lookahead.